# Error: Failed to lookup view "list" in views directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, express, ejs

These are the images

[its my code for app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QL33.png)

[its my code for list.ejs in views directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4rDv.png)

and my index.html is empty.
this is the full error log:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "list" in views directory "C:\Users\amita\Desktop\Development\todolist-v1/views"
    at Function.render (C:\Users\amita\Desktop\Development\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\amita\Desktop\Development\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\Users\amita\Desktop\Development\todolist-v1\app.js:23:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\amita\Desktop\Development\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\amita\Desktop\Development\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\amita\Desktop\Development\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\amita\Desktop\Development\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\amita\Desktop\Development\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\amita\Desktop\Development\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\amita\Desktop\Development\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

someone can help me?
thanks!

Comment: Have a look at your path

Answer (score 0):

By the look of the path in the error, I think it's an issue between `/` and `\` (linux vs windows paths).
Try to replace the view set on l.6 with:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
```

path.join will handle the path formatting for you.
You will have to import it too:

```
const path = require('path');
```